# How to create internationalized blog with Strapi using Next.js getStaticPaths & getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, strapi

I have a problem figuring out how to localize my content with Next.js and Strapi.

my current file structure looks like so:

```
pages/ 
   blog/ 
    - [post].tsx
    - portfolio.tsx
```

Inside portfolio I am fetching data for all posts created on Strapi, depending on which locale is currently set, like so:

```
  export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.com/api/articles?locale=${locale}&populate=*`
  );
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      articles: data.data,
    },
  };
};
```

In [post] it looks like that:

```
  export const getStaticPaths = async ({ locales, locale }) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.com/api/articles?locale=${locale}&populate=*`
  );

  const data = await res.json()

  const ids = data.data.map((post: any) => post.id);
  const paths = ids
    .map((id: any) =>
      locales.map((locale: any) => ({
        params: { post: id.toString() },
        locale,
      }))
    )
    .flat();

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
  const id = context.params.post;
 
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.tincors.com/api/articles/${id}?populate=*`
  );

  const res_blocks = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.tincors.com/api/articles/${id}?populate[blocks][populate]=*`
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  const blocks_data = await res_blocks.json();
  const block_data_slider = blocks_data.data.attributes.blocks[0].files.data;
  return {
    props: { article: data.data, slider: block_data_slider },
  };
};
```

Note that each article on Strapi has different id for it's localized version - so as an example:
article_1_pl has id of 10
but it's english variant has id of 12.

fun fact - on portfolio.tsx data is fetched successfully, and post miniature cards are properly displaying based on the current domain (on dev I am using two different hosts for i18n - **localhost:3000** for PL & **example.com:3000** for EN).

However once I try to redirect myself to the full article, by clicking on the post miniature card, I get the 404 page not found error in the browser, with these errors poping each second in the console logs [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp7af.png).
It doesn't matter which local host I am currently at.

cards are wrapped in a `<Link href="/blog/${id}" locale={route.locale} />`

However the moment I change my code in [post].tsx by removing the "locale" from the endpoint:

```
   const res = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.com/api/articles?locale=${locale}&populate=*`
  );
```

to:

```
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://strapi.com/api/articles?populate=*`
  );
```

suddenly **each of my PL articles** on **localhost:3000** are displayed properly, and only the english variants aren't working (404 page not found).

I assume that it is due to the fact, that by removing the "locale" from the API endpoint it only fetches the polish articles, not the english ones, but it baffles me why it's not working at all, when I use the localized endpoint source.

**How I want my app to work:**

I want article description (which is generated as a dynamic route) to display in active language, by fetching localized data by the post id.

**My question is:**

How do I fetch the proper localized data from Strapi in [post].tsx
when using getStaticPaths & getStaticProps. What is wrong with above code and how do I fix it?

I apologize if the above description is too chaotic to understand - feel free to ask for more explanations if necessary :)